# Anchor doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, href

I have a problem with link inside page. This is part of jQuery code I use in my page

```
$.fn.stopAtTop= function () {
  var $this = this,
      $window = $(window),
      thisPos = $this.offset().top,
      //thisPreservedTop = $this.css("top"),
      setPosition,
      under,
      over;

  under = function(){
    if ($window.scrollTop() < thisPos) {
        $this.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: ""
        });
        setPosition = over;
    }
  };

  over = function(){
    if (!($window.scrollTop() < thisPos)){
        $this.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 0
        });
        setPosition = under;
    }
  };

  setPosition = over;

  $window.resize(function()
  {
    bumperPos = pos.offset().top;
    thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
    setPosition();
  });

  $window.scroll(function(){setPosition();});
  setPosition();
};
```

And this is a example [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/masza/jx8nmhfq/)

When I scroll down everything works fine but when I want go to the top of the page it's impossible. I know that issue is that the script makes the `div` fixed, but I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: In your html at the demo, you link to `#four` in both links, is this intentional?

Comment: No, that was a mistake. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a click handler that scrolls to the top of the page:

```
$("[href='#one']").click(function() {
    scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

[jsfiddle.net/jx8nmhfq/1](https://jsfiddle.net/jx8nmhfq/1/)

Comment: Awsome! Thank you :-) I need something exactly what you write,  something like "look,  that is so easy", because I lost a lot of time to looking for the solution.